# How do you change the default program to open a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, stl

I'm using os.startfile(path\file.stl) to open an STL file. By default, the STL file is opened in the program Print 3D (using Windows 10). I would like my Python program to not open the STL file in the default program, but rather in Paint 3D (or a different stl viewing program of my choosing). How do I open a file in the non-default program?

```
import os
os.startfile(r'C:\Users\my\path\to\file.stl')
#opens file.stl in default program, not the program I would like
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) suggest that there's no way to do that (at least no way with `os.startfile`).

> the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its extension is associated.

Comment: Would you know of different way to do this, other than os.startfile?